# How to access TestCase instance method from Mock instance method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

## TL;DR

Can I access the current `unittest.TestCase` instance from within a method of a mock class without explicitly passing in that instance? If not, what is the proper way to access the assertion helper functions of `TestCase` (which are instance methods) from there? (Is there a proper way?)

## The Szenario: Augmenting `MagicMock` with my own assertion method that builds upon a `TestCase` method

I'd like to test that one function (`handle_multiple_foobars()`) uses another function (`handle_one_foobar()`) correctly, so I'm mocking `handle_one_foobar()`. 'Correctly' here means that `handle_multiple_foobars()` shall call `handle_one_foobar()` for each of its arguments individually. (One `handle_one_foobar()` call per `handle_multiple_foobars()` argument.) I don't care about the order of the calls.

### Checking whether *all* expected calls to the mock have been made

Thus, I've started with this:

```
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch, call

def handle_one_foobar(foobar):
    raise NotImplementedError()

def handle_multiple_foobars(foobars):
    for foobar in reversed(foobars):
        handle_one_foobar(foobar)


class FoobarHandlingTest(TestCase):
    @patch('__main__.handle_one_foobar')
    def test_handle_multiple_foobars_calls_handle_one_foobar_for_each_foobar(
            self, handle_one_foobars_mock):
        foobars = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz']

        handle_multiple_foobars(foobars)

        expected_calls = [call(fb) for fb in foobars]
        handle_one_foobars_mock.assert_has_calls(
                expected_calls,
                any_order=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

### Checking whether *only* expected calls to the mock have been made

However, this would also pass if there were more calls to the mocked function, e.g.

```
def handle_multiple_foobars(foobars):
    handle_one_foobar('begin')
    for foobar in reversed(foobars):
        handle_one_foobar(foobar)
    handle_one_foobar('end')
```

I don't want that.

I could easily write an additional assertion (or an additional test) to check for the total count of calls. But I'd like this to be treated as a single condition to test. So I've constructed a different assertion:

```
class FoobarHandlingTest(TestCase):
    @patch('__main__.handle_one_foobar')
    def test_handle_multiple_foobars_calls_handle_one_foobar_for_each_foobar(
            self, handle_one_foobar_mock):
        foobars = ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz']

        handle_multiple_foobars(foobars)

        expected_calls = [call(fb) for fb in foobars]
        self.assertCountEqual(
                handle_one_foobar_mock.mock_calls,
                expected_calls)
```

This would catch the additional calls nicely:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: test_handle_multiple_foobars_calls_handle_one_foobar_for_each_foobar (__main__.FoobarHandlingTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/unittest/mock.py", line 1136, in patched
    return func(*args, **keywargs)
  File "convenientmock.py", line 23, in test_handle_multiple_foobars_calls_handle_one_foobar_for_each_foobar
    expected_calls)
AssertionError: Element counts were not equal:
First has 1, Second has 0:  call('begin')
First has 1, Second has 0:  call('end')

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

### Move the new assertion into a helper method of the mock

But for my taste, it's not obvious enough what's being asserted here. Therefore, I decided to extract the assertion into a new function. Because this function serves a very similar purpose as `assert_has_calls()`, I feel it should be a method of the mock class. It's not hard to extend `MagicMock` and we can even make the extracted method a bit more generic in allowing to specify whether call order should matter or not:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class MyMock(MagicMock):
    def assert_has_exactly_calls(_mock_self, calls, any_order=False):
        tc = TestCase()
        asserter = tc.assertCountEqual if any_order else tc.assertEqual
        asserter(_mock_self.mock_calls, list(calls))
```

`@patch` will use this class instead of `unittest.mock.MagicMock` to create the mock when I change the test method decoration to

```
    @patch('__main__.handle_one_foobar', new_callable=MyMock)
    def test_handle_multiple_foobars_calls_handle_one_foobar_for_each_foobar( # ...
```

I can then write my assertion as

```
        handle_one_foobar_mock.assert_has_exactly_calls(
                expected_calls,
                any_order=True)
```

### ... and the ugly

But you might have noticed something very ugly: To be able to use `TestCase` instance methods `assertCountEqual()` and `assertEqual()`, I've created a dummy `TestCase` instance that isn't the real `FoobarHandlingTest` instance in which the test runs.

How can I avoid this?

Obviously, I could pass the test's `self` into the assertion method, but that'd make for a very non-intuitive signature. (Why should I have to tell an assertion about my test case?)

Comment: Why not just add a non-test instance method to `FoobarHandlingTest` that abstracts the code around your assertions?

Comment: Well, as said: "Because this function serves a very similar purpose as assert_has_calls() [a method of `Mock` and by extension of `MagicMock`], I feel it should be a method of the mock class." thus, **for consistency of interface**. And I really like the signature (calling it on the mock instead of passing in the mock). Also, I might want to use it in other `TestCase`s , too, or even propose it as an addition to `Mock` upstream.

Comment: It might well be that what I want isn't possible in a non-ugly manner.

Comment: A workaround would be to replace `TestCase().assertCountEqual` and `TestCase().assertEqual` with [`hamcrest.contains_inanyorder`](https://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.org/en/V1.8.2/sequence_matchers/#module-hamcrest.library.collection.issequence_containinginanyorder) and [`hamcrest.contains`](https://pyhamcrest.readthedocs.org/en/V1.8.2/sequence_matchers/#module-hamcrest.library.collection.issequence_containinginorder) from [`PyHamcrest`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyHamcrest), respectively, which provide similar functionality but are standalone and thus do not depend on a `TestCase` instance.